# How to convert date format of selected cells using Google Apps Script

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am fairly new to Google Apps Script and I am trying to create a function where it converts the selected cells to a dd/mm/yyyy format. The format the dates are in originally looks like this 2022-01-03 15:00:00 +1100.

I've managed to change the format of the date so it shows up correctly on the logger but when I select the cells and run the function via a menu it just shows up as the last value.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you!!!

```
function dateconverter(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var selectedContent = ss.getActiveRange().getValues();
var getRange = ss.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()
for(var x =0;x<selectedContent.length;x++){

var fixed = selectedContent[x].join().split(' ');
var dateStr = fixed[0].split('-').join()
var year = +dateStr.substring(0, 4)
var month = +dateStr.substring(5, 7)
var day = +dateStr.substring(8, 10)
var pubdate = [`${day}/${month}/${year}`]
Logger.log(pubdate)

}
ss.getRange(getRange).setValue(pubdate)
}
```

Comment: About `create a function where it converts the selected cells to a dd/mm/yyyy format`, can you provide the sample values of `var selectedContent = ss.getActiveRange().getValues();`? And, in your situation, the selected cells are the date objects? And, do you want to convert the date object to the string type? Or, do you want to convert the date format while the date object is kept?

Comment: @Tanaike the selected content we get from cliniko looks like this and unfortunately google sheets doesn't recognise this format as a date so basically I need a way to convert this string to a date with the format dd/mm/yyyy: 

2022-01-01 11:00:00 +1100

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use :- `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getTimeZone,"dd/MM/yyyy")`